# Solution for checking repetitive elements in the matrix[1000][1000]

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, matrix

Need to write function for checking repetitive elements in the matrix[1000][1000]. Return True if found any repetitive elements, and False if not.

I think need to make the solution with two steps: 
1. Sort every elements in the matrix from smaller to bigger (during sorting we can check the elements on equality) Using merge sort for example.
2. Compare previous and next element one by one from first to last element in the matrix.

Is efficiency of this solution good enough?

Comment: @JerryGoyal OP has included tag 'c' not c++

Comment: It is fast enough if it is fast enough... The most obvious, least optimized solution is sometimes fast enough. We cannot answer this for you. Write your algorithm. Make sure it is correct. Then profile and decide if you should make it faster or not.

Comment: If all you are looking for is duplicate, you can collapse the matrix into an array (ie 2D to 1D), then sort, then compare consecutive elements for equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), and it does not seem it is important that your array is 2D, you can regard it as a "regular" array, and solve it with the "regular" solution of element distinctness, which is:

1. Sort the array, then iterate the elements and check if there is an index `i` such that `arr[i] == arr[i+1]`. 

   This solution is `O(nlogn)` time, assuming efficient sort, with little extra space needed.
2. Store the elements in a hash-set, and when inserting each element - check if the element already exists in the set.

   This solution is `O(n)` time on *average*, and `O(n^2)` time *worst case*, and needs `O(n)` extra space.

Comment: I did not get it how you got the average and worst case time complexity in point 2, could you explain ? Is it with respect to a specific hash function ?

Comment: @sasha hash table's insertion is O(1) average case and O(n) wort case, repeat for n elements and you get this complexity.